# How to restore backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, restore

I took a backup of a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 via SSMS backup utility and restored the same backup in SQL Server 2014 via SSMS backup utility and the database restore. It was successful but am not seeing any tables in SQL Server 2014 after restoring the database. Can someone help me to restore the SQL Server 2008 R2 database backup (`.bak`) in 2014?

Comment: This should be a no-brainer and should just work just fine. Did you **refresh** the Object Explorer in SQL Server 2014 after the restore?

Comment: yes I did refresh after the restore

Comment: Connect to the database and run `select * from sys.tables`. What do you see?

Comment: Also run this: `SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDB'; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql 2008 r2 database backup file should be completely compatible on sql 2014. you can try to restore the database on sql 2008 r2 at first, and check if the table was deleted before the backing up.